# Returning a list of items that are raising an AttributeError when using geopy and try/except?

Tags: python, list, error-handling, try-except, geopy

I am attempting to get the latitude and longitude for ~400 locations using geopy. However, many of the addresses are returning 'None' as they are either not specific enough or are intersections of streets, which is causing an "AttributeError: 'None' type has no attribute 'latitude'" and an exit of the for loop.

What I would like to do is run the for loop without exiting due to error AND return a list of all of the locations prompting errors so that I can hard code a proper address for them.

My current code is as follows:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()
coordinates = []

def station_errors(list_of_stations):
    for station in list_of_stations:
        try:
            location = geolocator.geocode(str(i)) #line with error, used 'i' instead of 'station'
            lat_long = (location.latitude, location.longitude)
            coordinates.append(list(lat_long))
        except Exception:
            print("Error: %s"%(station))
            continue
```

However, this seems to be printing out every station regardless of whether geopy was able to assign it a latitude and longitude, as I've tried many of them manually. I only want the stations that raised an error/were unable to receive a lat/long coordinate.

I am fairly new to 'try, except, continue' error testing, so any advice is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

My initial error was using 'i' instead of 'station', an error which I've left in the original question. The code that I got to work and gives me the result that I want is as follows:

```
def station_errors(list_of_stations):
    list_of_error_stations = []
    for station in list_of_stations:
        try:
            location = geolocator.geocode(str(station + " DC"))
            lat_long = (location.latitude, location.longitude)
            coordinates.append(list(lat_long))
        except Exception:
            list_of_error_stations.append(station)
            continue
    return(list_of_error_stations)
```

Comment: in that code, if they get printed, you have to have thrown an exception. In your manual tests, did you use the same code? I'd hazard a guess the geocode method is throwing on account of some connextion error

Comment: The geocode was throwing an exception, but for a reason of stupidity on my part: I was using str(i) instead of str(station). Fixing this prints out each station that throws an exception, which can be reformatted into a list as I'll demonstrate in an edit to my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect that the "*AttributeError: 'None' type has no attribute 'latitude'*" is given in the line:

```
lat_long = (location.latitude, location.longitude)
```

thous I would transform the code in something like:

```
def station_errors(list_of_stations):
    for station in list_of_stations:
        location = geolocator.geocode(str(i))
        coordinates.append([location.latitude, location.longitude] if location is not None else None)
        # or coordinates.append(list(lat_long) if location is not None else [None, None])
        # which ever comes more in handy
    return coordinates

coords = station_errors(los)
# and then deal with the Nones (or [None, None] s ) to "hard code a proper address for them"
```